# Office JavaScript API from Node.js?

Tags: office-js

We need to work with a large number of documents in an automated fashion. For example, merge several PPT and Word files and output PDF. This needs to be done without any user interaction. For example, from a web server application or a command line application.

We will like to do this using an official SDK. What is our best option? Is it possible to use the Office JavaScript API from a command line tool written in Node.js?

Comment: Juan's answer is correct, but I'd like to get a bit more info from you so that I can better understand/channel your feedback.  Are you looking to just *generate* new documents (export-like scenario), or are you looking to automate existing files that are stored in the cloud?

Comment: My files are in my local hard drive. I have many different use cases. One of them being merging many different powerpoint files into one and exporting PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately any extension via Office.js needs to have affinity with one document. The automation you are describing should be coded using the OOXML SDK.

Comment: Juan Balmori, can a add a button in my node.js based web app and by clicking this button, office word open to edit and save back site's read-only content? 
Can I do this using Office Word API ?